# Super Simple Tasker on ARM Cortex

Tags: c, assembly, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I read article [Build a Super Simple Tasker](https://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4025691/Build-a-Super-Simple-Tasker) and I like the idea. It's very simple scheduler, but he has real-time and preemptive multitasking with a single stackit. I like the idea, but when I tried to write this program for a modern microcontroller (ARM Cortex-M), I failed.  In book "The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3" in chapter "9.2 Exception Exits" is written, that this microcontroller has not different EOI and RETI instructions (or its analogue). In this microcontroller: return interrupt handler == EOI == RETI ?

Someone (expert assembler) can tell me how I can replace the commands RETI and EOI from the article for ARM Cortex-M microcontroller?

Comment: [Read the friendly manual here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html). I found it with www.google.com.

Comment: So, uh, literally your first project on an ARM processor is a multi-tasking scheduler?

Comment: @unwind "hello world!" is too 1990-ish

Comment: I write letter from Miro Samek and hi write anser for me.

Comment: the cortex-m3 is a cortex-m microcontroller, what microcontroller are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

Author (Miro Samek) wrote to me how to do this for the Cortex-M. Theory: https://www.state-machine.com/qpc/arm-cm_qk.html  Code: https://github.com/QuantumLeaps/qpc/blob/master/ports/arm-cm/qk/gnu/qk_port.c